# Why is .detach() throwing error in array of DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering why I'm getting error "$groceryItems[i].detach is not a function" when I'm able to see that $groceryItems[i] is indeed a DOM element as a result of logging it?

I have only included the script and not the ejs view.

```
<script>
function sortByAvgRating() {

var $groceryItems = $('.groceryItems');//grab all of the grocery items

for (var i = $groceryItems.length; i--; ) {//detach each grocery item from the DOM
    console.log('$groceryItems[i] ', $groceryItems[i]);
    $groceryItems[i].detach();
}

$groceryItems.sort(function(a, b) {//sort the grocery items by the rating attribute
    return +a.children[1].children[0].children[0].dataset.rating - 
        +b.children[1].children[0].children[0].dataset.rating;
}).
appendTo('groceryItemsContainer');//apppend the sorted array of elements to the DOM
}

</script>
```

Comment: because... it isn't a function of a dom node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ibrahim mahir's answer explains why your code doesn't work.

But you don't need to write a loop to detach all the elements in a jQuery object. When you apply jQuery modification functions to a collection, it automatically performs it on all elements.

So you can simply write:

```
$groceryItems.detach();
```

And when you want to loop over the elements in a collection, use `.each()`:

```
$groceryItems.each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).detach();
});
```

Comment: Why do you use `each` to iterate over a collection? I've always kind of wondered this actually. It doesn't give you immediate access to the jQuery wrapped element like you'd sort of expect it to, the order of the arguments is different than native `forEach` which is stupid imo but whatever. I don't get the usefulness.

Comment: @1252748 It was probably more useful with earlier browsers that didn't all implement standard Javascript looping constructs (e.g. IE8 doesn't have `forEach`), so it was a useful shim. Now I just do it for consistency -- if I'm using jQuery, I stick with its methods.

Answer (score 0):

`$groceryItems` is a jQuery object that has the function `detach` defined on it, but `$groceryItems[i]` is the raw DOM element at the index `i`. DOM elements don't have a function called `detach`.

Wrap the element in a jQuery object before calling `detach`:

```
$( $groceryItems[i] ).detach();
```

Or use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of `[]` (`eq` will return a jQuery object that has `detach` defined on it):

```
$groceryItems.eq(i).detach();
//           ^^^^^^
```